# Which preposition to use after “statistic”?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should one use after *statistic* when one wants to say what object this statistic describes? Consider, for instance, the following sentence taken from Google Translate:

> He quoted a government statistic that suggests foreign coverage has gone down on British television by 40% in the last decade.

If one was to say what he quoted, would one say

1. “a government statistic **about** foreign coverage on British television,”
2. “a government statistic **for** foreign coverage on British television,”
3. “a government statistic **of** foreign coverage on British television,” or
4. “a government statistic **on** foreign coverage on British television”?

Personally, I want to use *about*, but then I was corrected for doing so. Google Ngram also [disagrees](https://goo.gl/3fSSWJ) with me.

I originally phrased this question focusing primarily on the singular form, *statistic*, as I assumed there would be no difference with respect to the plural one, *statistics*. However, according to the comments, there is a different. Since I’m equally much interested in the plural form, I’m extending this question to cover *statistics* as well.

Regarding *statistics*, I’ve [found](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/statistics) the following examples:

> If all the industries belong to one economic area over which, so far as we can tell from general statistics **of** wages and prices, and other information, fairly homogeneous conditions prevailed, we may be able to reach some useful conclusions as to the operation of the act.
>
> The statistics **of** civil proceedings vary considerably from province to province.
>
> The Trans-Caspian railway has been an important factor; almost all the cotton exported passes over this line, and the statistics **of** this trade indicate the progress made.
>
> Statistics **of** offences, including contravvenzioni or breaches of by-laws and regulations, exhibit a considerable increase per 100,000 inhabitants since 1887, and only a slight diminution on the figures of 1897.

So which preposition should one use after *statistics*?

Comment: 5. All of the above.

Comment: 6 - *regarding*, 7 - *concerning*, 8 - *relating to...*

Comment: @Robusto, I’d like to choose one and use it consistently in my writing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes, there are other ways to phrase this.

Comment: You have to be careful with NGrams. The usage of 'for' isn't the same sense as the one you want. For example "The t-statistic for testing the regression model..."

Comment: I'd be careful about choosing one preposition and using it consistently. Sometimes changing the object changes the preposition. For example, there's a good chance I'd say, "A government statistic **on** the use of cell phones," but, "a government statistic **about** rising homeless rates." This notion that a noun is always followed by the same preposition is a myth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate preposition depends whether what follows the preposition is the precise definition of the single statistic that follows the preposition (in which case **for** is the only appropriate option, or whether it is a general description of the statistic, in which case all of your suggestions are appropriate.

> The statistic **for** perinatal mortalities in Cambodia in 2016 is quite shocking.
>
> He produced a statistic **for/about/on/of** perinatal mortalities to support the need for extra funding.

The options available depend, therefore, on how specific you are in the text that immediately follows the preposition. If it defines a speficic statistic or class of statistics, then only **for** is valid:

> government statistics **for** the proportion of foreign coverage on British television over the past decade...

If, however, you use less specific terminology, all of the options that you have suggested are reasonable:

> government statistics **for/about/on/of** foreign coverage on British television...

Comment: I don't buy the idea that singular/plural ***statistic/s*** meaningfully influences the preferred preposition.

Comment: I’ve updated my question. I’d be grateful if you could revisit your answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, agreed. It's about whether you are specific, which is more likely to occur with a single statistic but can equally occur with a group of class of statistics. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Even just reconsidering your *original* text now, a few days after the post, I think my downvote was a bit OTT. But it does seem better now with reference to "specific" rather than "singular". Personally, I think that ***a statistic*** in most contexts would usually be more naturally called ***a value***. But maybe it's an age thing - [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+statistic%2Cthe+statistics&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20statistic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20statistics%3B%2Cc0) shows singular gaining traction.